# passing data to view via intended when login

Tags: laravel

I am trying to pass an array to view when user login by:

```
$users = User::all();

return redirect()
   ->intended('/home', compact('users'))
   ->with(['user_login_success' =>  __('messages.mobile_user_login')]);
```

in home.blade.php

```
@foreach ($users as $user)                            
  <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->name }}</option>                                                          
@endforeach
```

My error:

> ErrorException Undefined variable: users (View:
> C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\resources\views\home.blade.php).

Comment: That's not how you pass data on a redirect. Do `->with(['users' => $users, 'user_login_success' => __('messages.mobile_user_login')])`, then you can access users via `$users = session()->get('users')`

Comment: `intended()` creates a redirect response, it does not render a view, you need to pass the `$users` in the controller where you are accessing the `home.blade.php` view.

Comment: I am already  trying ``` ->with(['users' => $users, 'user_login_success' => __('messages.mobile_user_login')]) ``` same result

Comment: Did you do the 2nd part? In your Controller for `/home`, you need to define `$users` as `$users = session()->get('users')`

Answer (score 1):

Your redirect should include the `$users` object, like so:

```
return redirect()
   ->intended('/home')
   ->with([
     'user_login_success' =>  __('messages.mobile_user_login'),
     'users' => $users,
   ]);
```

When using `Redirect::intended()->with('users', $users);` the data is now flashed in the session. The data will now be available via sessions for **only** this request.

You can now retrieve it from the session facade.

```
@if (isset(Session::get('users'))

  @foreach (Session::get('users') as $user)                            
    <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->name }}</option>                                                          
  @endforeach

@endif
```

Comment: working for once session ... great // but i want to render a view for all time

Comment: @ahmadalmasri Then you need to put it inside its own route and then redirect to it, passing the data through the controller. Just like how you did this page.

Comment: can i send $user in this section `protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;`

Comment: @ahmadalmasri Only through a session, you're better off creating your own route for it like exampled in my comment above.

Comment: I found a solution in HomeController  like:`    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        return view('home', ['users' => $users]);
    }` THANKS to everybody

Comment: Yes exactly. :)